# Validations for Image upload is not working in yii

Tags: file, yii, upload

Here is my  view code :

```
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
        'id'=>'user-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>'true',
        'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
)
);?>

  <div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'profile_image');?>
  <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'profile_image');?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'profile_image');?>
  </div>
```

& this is the rule for validations:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array (array('profile_image','file','types'=>'jpg','allowEmpty'=>true),
);
}
```

Still,it is not showing any validations for file upload.Can anyone please tell me the error in my code.

Comment: please post your controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your Controller for validation

```
$model = new YourModel();

if(isset($_POST['YourModel']))
{
$model->profile_image= CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profile_image');

if($model->validate())
{
// do your task here
}
}
```

**Hope this will help you :)**